# HTML Tags from Website does not appear on saved HTML File

Tags: html, automation

Hi I am working with an IBM Curam Website Automation testing
When I logged in and inspect element, certain elements like search filters for person appears.
But when I saved the html page, the tags for this search box is not in the saved file.
Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

They may be added or made visible from server side language? (php, asp ...)

Comment: ok, how do you trace to where this html tags supposed to be originally from?

Comment: Could you provide a use case ?

Comment: i dont have the rights to share the code detail here. Im hoping for someone who has knowledge on IBM Curam UIM layout to help explain further how the html pages are formed